# slideshow not initially appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

I'm trying to add a slideshow over my website's header, but on the initially loading the slides don't show up, and instead I'm left with the dots and arrows, but way higher located than it should be. After i click on a dot or "next page" arrow, the images are displayed normally, at least until I reach the end of the slides, then the images will vanish again and the arrows and dots will "jump up". I'm honestly sorry if this is a simple problem, I'm in no way a pro at coding, I'm just a newbie and I hit a wall, and after two days of trying on my own/searching for similar questions here, I thought I might as well ask. Any help at all is appreciated!

```js
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 740px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:76px;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left:-52px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  color: #792828;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  left:800px;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}

/* Town Info */
.towninfo {
    height:260px;
    width: 370px;
    background-color: #101010;
    border: 1px solid #0d0c0c;
    margin-top:auto;
    font-family: 'Constantia'; 
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 25px;
    color:#958c8c;
    display: inline-block;

}

.towninfo2 {
    height:260px;
    width: 370px;
    background-color: #101010;
    border: 1px solid #0d0c0c;
    margin-top:auto;
    font-family: 'Constantia'; 
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 25px;
    color:#958c8c;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://static.tumblr.com/uk6ur9p/5A9pbh7ft/middleimage.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://static.tumblr.com/uk6ur9p/C9Tpbh5fi/middleimage2.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="towninfo">Caption Three</div><div class="towninfo2">dfvdfdfdfdfdfdfdf</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're vanishing at the end and "jumping up," it sounds like 1) no expected data is set (such as an image in this case) and 2) because of that the original stylesheet css is being used (the display:none;).

I noticed your third slide is this:

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="towninfo">Caption Three</div><div class="towninfo2">dfvdfdfdfdfdfdfdf</div>
</div>
```

Rather than an image. Have your tried replacing this with just a image like the other two and see if it functions properly?

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but as far as I could tell there was no empty slider. The "display:none" does make the images show up... But they show up all piled up under each other at once which is not exactly desirable.
Also yes! I thought this could be the problem also, but replacing it with an image did not work, the problem continued. It also appears normal during the slideshow once I actually click an arrow or bullet and get it work.